# Show that the following homomorphism is well defined.

Tags: number-theory

I was given this exercise, based on a theorem from Cox's book, which can be found [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eila/Cox-Primes_of_the_form_x2+ny2.pdf).

**Theorem.**  Let $D=4n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$. Then, there is a unique homomorphism $\chi: (\Bbb Z/D\Bbb Z)^{\times}\rightarrow\{\pm 1\}$ such that $\chi([p])=(D/p)$ for all primes $p$ that do not divide $D$.

*Show that this homomorphism is well-defined.*

Here is my attempt:

We will show that for two primes $x$ and $y$ that do not divide $D$ that are congruent modulo $D$, we have $(D/x)=(D/y)$. To this end, let's write $y=x+mD$ for $m\in\Bbb Z$ and $n=p_1p_2...p_r$ where $p_1,...,p_r$ are primes.

If $n$ is odd, we have $$\Big(\frac{D}{x+mD}\Big)=\Big(\frac{p_1}{x+mD}\Big)...\Big(\frac{p_r}{x+mD}\Big)=\pm\Big(\frac{x+mD}{p_1}\Big)...\Big(\frac{x+mD}{p_r}\Big).$$ As all the primes divide $D$, we further have that $$\Big(\frac{x+mD}{p_1}\Big)...\Big(\frac{x+mD}{p_r}\Big)=\Big(\frac{x}{p_1}\Big)...\Big(\frac{x}{p_r}\Big).$$ As $4$ divides $D$, we have that $D$ and $x+mD$ have the same congruence modulo $4$, and so $$\Big(\frac{D}{x+mD}\Big)=\pm\Big(\frac{x}{p_1}\Big)...\Big(\frac{x}{p_r}\Big)=\Big(\frac{p_1}{x}\Big)...\Big(\frac{p_r}{x}\Big)=\Big(\frac{D}{p}\Big).$$
If $n$ is even, as $x$ and $x+mD$ have the same congruence modulo $8$, we have that $(2/x)=(2/x+mD)$ and the rest of the argument follows in the same way as above.

---

However, when I sent it to my professor, he said that there is a bit more work to do as I have actually shown that $(D/x)=\pm(D/y)$. If this is indeed the case, then I am not sure what else I need to do to in fact show that $(D/x)=(D/y)$.

In the actual book, Cox uses the Jacobi symbol, however I have not been exposed to it so I cannot use it. I feel like I need to use quadratic reciprocity but not sure how to do so exactly.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to count the minus signs coming from the application of quadratic reciprocity to show that both applications yield the same factor overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x\equiv y\pmod D$, so in particular $x\equiv y\pmod 4$.

Write $D=\prod_{i=1}^m p_i$ (with repetition allowed).
By quadratic reciprocity, we have
$$\left(\frac Dx\right)=\prod_{i=1}^m\left(\frac {p_i}x\right)=(-1)^k\prod_{i=1}^m\left(\frac x{p_i}\right)$$
where $k$ is the number of indices $i$ for which $x\equiv p_i\equiv 3\pmod 4$. But as  $x\equiv y\pmod 4$, this number is the same if we use $y$ instead of $x$. (Strictly speking, I mishandle the cases $p_i=2$ above, but you get the gist)

Comment: Ah, that's brilliant - thank you very much!