# Show that the following function is a homomorphism.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, legendre-symbol

This is part (2) of the question that I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837265/show-that-the-following-homomorphism-is-well-defined). Inspired by the answer in this question, I want to see if I am on the right track with this question.

I was given this exercise, based on a theorem from Cox's book, which can be found [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eila/Cox-Primes_of_the_form_x2+ny2.pdf).

**Theorem.**  Let $D=4n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$. Then, there is a unique homomorphism $\chi: (\Bbb Z/D\Bbb Z)^{\times}\rightarrow\{\pm 1\}$ such that $\chi([p])=(D/p)$ for all primes $p$ that do not divide $D$.

*Show that this function is a homomorphism.*

Here is my attempt:

Let $x$ and $y$ be primes with $m$ being chosen so that $xy+mD$ is prime. Then, we observe that $xy+mD\equiv 3\bmod 4$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are not in the same congruence class modulo $4$. ***We define $n$ to be the number of indices $i$ where $xy\equiv 3\bmod 4$***

\begin{align*}
    \chi([xy])=\Big(\frac{D}{xy+mD}\Big)&=\prod_{i=1}^k\Big(\frac{p_i}{xy+mD}\Big)\\
    &=(-1)^n\prod_{i=1}^k\Big(\frac{xy+mD}{p_i}\Big)\\
    &=(-1)^n\prod_{i=1}^k\Big(\frac{xy}{p_i}\Big)\\
    &=(-1)^{2n}\prod_{i=1}^k\Big(\frac{p_i}{xy}\Big)\\
    &=\prod_{i=1}^k\Big(\frac{p_i}{x}\Big)\Big(\frac{p_i}{y}\Big)\\
    &=\Big(\frac{D}{x}\Big)\Big(\frac{D}{y}\Big)\\
    &=\chi([x])\chi([y])
\end{align*}

It's the bolded sentence that I'm not too confident in right now. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: "*Show that this homomorphism is a homomorphism.*" Isn't this tautological? By the way, the Legendre symbol itself satisfies this: $ \left({\frac  {a}{p}}\right)\cdot \left({\frac  {b}{p}}\right)=\left({\frac  {a\cdot b}{p}}\right)$.

Comment: Yes sorry, should say a function I suppose. First we need to "get rid" of that $mD$ term though right?